# How to prevent generic usage of a certain API (e.g Streaming API or Builder API) with ArchUnit?

Tags: archunit

Given a set of classes where it should not be forbidden to use certain APIs (for whatever reason).

For example, prohibiting Java 8 Streaming API, or calling a [Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) inner class because you want to force the usage of loops and constructors for particular classes.

The critical part is that you do not know the `ownerName` beforehand and there is no `callMethod(methodName)` where I could coarse-grainy disallow calling `stream()` or `build()` methods.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compose powerful `ArchRule`s using predicates instead of the fluent API; in your case with
[`.callMethodWhere(DescribedPredicate<? super JavaMethodCall> predicate)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/lang/syntax/elements/ClassesShould.html#callMethodWhere(com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate)).

To prevent the usage of `someCollection.stream()`, you could start with [`HasName.Predicates.`*`name`*](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/properties/HasName.Predicates.html#name(java.lang.String)):

```java
noClasses().should().callMethodWhere(name("stream"))
```

To avoid false-positives, the rule should probably become more specific.

ArchUnit ships lots of useful pre-defined predicates; you just need to find them (and possibly deal with their covariant parameter types via [`DescribedPredicate.forSubtype`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/base/DescribedPredicate.html#forSubtype())):

```java
noClasses().should().callMethodWhere(target(
    name("stream").<CodeUnitCallTarget>forSubtype().and(
        owner(assignableTo(Collection.class)).<CodeUnitCallTarget>forSubtype().and(
                rawParameterTypes(new Class[0])
        )
    )
))
```

I personally find it simpler to define a custom predicate instead (e.g. using
[`DescribedPredicate.`*`describe`*](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/base/DescribedPredicate.html#describe(java.lang.String,com.tngtech.archunit.base.Predicate))):

```java
noClasses().should().callMethodWhere(target(describe("is Collection.stream()",
    target -> "stream".equals(target.getName()) &&
            target.getOwner().isAssignableTo(Collection.class) &&
            target.getParameterTypes().isEmpty()
)))
```

FYI: My solution uses the following imports:

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.describe;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaCall.Predicates.target;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass.Predicates.assignableTo;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.HasName.Predicates.name;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.HasOwner.Predicates.With.owner;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.HasParameterTypes.Predicates.rawParameterTypes;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;
```